# Failed to convert sequence data to a 3D tensor after the embedding

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am using sequence data ( RNA sequence ) for a classification task , so i wanted to try CNN , and i just figure out that after the data encoding ( i used the ordinal encoding ) that i must convert the input data encoding into 3D tensor , i still cant understand how i can do that so the input shape will be ( batch_size, sequence_lenght , num_features )

this is my code for the input data :

```py
# Pad sequences on the right with the provided character "_" to 11420 nts
pad_list = df['Seq'].str.ljust(11420,'_')
# Reduce length of sequences that are too long
pad_list = pad_list.map(lambda x: x[0:11420])
 
# encode the nucleotides into integers using Ordinal encoding
categories = ["A", "C", "G", "U" , "T", "N", "R", "K", "S", "Y", "M", "W", "D", "_"]
ordi = OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown="use_encoded_value", unknown_value=15)
ordi.fit(np.array(list(categories)).reshape(-1, 1))
 
pad_list= pad_list.map(lambda seq: ordi.transform(np.array(list(seq)).reshape(-1, 1)))
 
#convert the sequence to list of lists of integer than to a matrice
sequence_input= np.array(pad_list.to_list()).reshape((len(pad_list), len(pad_list[0])))`
```

i really tried to fing code for this type of data using cnn model , i didnt find a good code and i am new in this field so i really want to understand how we can use sequence data in cnn

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please fix the formatting of your "code" quote.